# Passing parameter from .aspx.cs to .ashx

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I want to pass a string to a .ashx page.

Normally I'll do it by setting a parameter in the .aspx page like for example: `Loader="TreeLoader.ashx?passedVariable=hello"`

But I want to do it programmatically on the .aspx.cs side because the value will change.

The .ashx page accepts a HTTPContext:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
```

Shouldn't there be some way to add a parameter to the context, and then get the parameter in a way similar to this:

```
string searchString = context.Request["searchString"];
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way will depend upon how the control is passed to the ashx from the aspx file. If the handler is called from server side (using `Server.Transfer` method) then you can use the context object itself. For example, in aspx.c file

```
HttpContext.Current["key"] = data;
Server.Transfer("TreeLoader.ashx");
```

And in ashx file

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var data = context["key"];
    ...
```

Advantage being you can pass the actual object as data (and not necessarily a string).

If call will be made from client (browser) side then you need to pass data as query string parameter - such as `TreeLoader.ashx?searchString=data` and use it in ashx as `context.Request["searchString"]`.

Comment: I am unable to get the server.transfer from the aspx page to transfer to the ashx page. I get the error - error executing the child request.

Comment: @MoizTankiwala, perhaps, your path to ashx is wrong OR there can be un-handled exception in your ashx OR your aspx page and ashx resides in different applications (same website but different app)!

Comment: The aspx and the ashx files are siblings in the same folder location. I am able to call the ashx simply by typing in the URL in the browser.

Comment: @MoizTankiwala, what is the exception that you get? You may try wrapping your `server.transfer` call in try-catch block - ignore ThreadAbortException and log any other exception to get more details including stack-trace!

Comment: Idk if is a .net change in the newer versions, but with .NET framework 4.5 i need to write HttpContext like below:
`HttpContext.Current.Application["my_key"] = my_value;`

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling tree handler from .aspx.cs? I think it will be same as 'TreeLoader.ashx?passedVariable=hello'  for eg: `Response.Redirect("TreeLoader.ashx?passedVariable=hello")`.