# Call to JavaScript function not working after opening email client with attachment

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
//send the email to the client as eml
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ContentType = "message/rfc822";
Response.AddHeader("content-length", bin.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"email.eml\"");
Response.OutputStream.Write(bin, 0, bin.Length);
Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

//This JavaScript call never fires.                       
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "closeLoading();", true);
```

It works fine when I remove the above code that sends the users a .eml file to open up their mail client.  I am basically trying to shut down a loading dialog after the process is finished. This is an older application that uses web forms in C#.

I open the Loading popup with a simple JavaScript call "loading.show();"

So far I have gathered that it is possible the ContentType is messing things up.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript method never fires it is because of `Response.Flush();` actually ends the response life cycle.

What you can do is create a new `ashx` file and do sending email operation there.

Let's say `DownloadMailHandler.ashx` file:

```
public class DownloadMailHandler : IHttpHandler  
{  
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)  
    {  
        var bin = null;//create email content
        context.Response.ClearHeaders();
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.Buffer = true;
        context.Response.ContentType = "message/rfc822";
        context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", bin.Length.ToString());
        context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"email.eml\"");
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(bin, 0, bin.Length);
        context.Response.Flush();
    }  
  
    public bool IsReusable  
    {  
        get  
        {  
            return false;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Then call the Javascript function and redirect to ashx to download email as following:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "closeLoading()", true);
Response.Redirect("DownloadMailHandler.ashx");
```

Note: You did not mention how you get your `bin` value but you can pass querystring to `ashx` and create `bin` object. See: [Passing parameter from .aspx.cs to .ashx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895197/passing-parameter-from-aspx-cs-to-ashx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  What you provided worked technically speaking but it did not solve the issue I was having.  Even after this the JavaScript dialog persisted.  As of now I just disabled the form so the could not resubmit it.  Again thanks so much for your time it did help me learn a bit about Generic Handlers.